# extract specific values from json data by combining 2 jq command

Tags: json, jq

I want to combine below mentioned 2 jq commands to work together in a single jq command.

**Command 1:**

```
jq -r '.objects[] | "\(.name),\(.uid),\(.type),\(."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv6-address"),\(."nat-settings"."install-on"),\(."nat-settings".method)"'
```

**Command 2:**

```
jq -r '.objects[].groups[].name'
```

I'm able to get output of commands when executed separately but I'm not getting any output after combining both.

**Combined command that I used:**

```
jq -r '.objects[] | "\(.name),\(.uid),\(.type),\(.["ipv4-address"]),\(.["nat-settings"]["ipv4-address"]),\(.["nat-settings"]["ipv6-address"]),\(.["nat-settings"]["install-on"]),\(.["nat-settings"]["method"]),\(.groups[]?.name)"'
```

Please help me correct this command.

**Input JSON Code:**

```
{
  "from" : 1,
  "to" : 1,
  "total" : 1,
  "objects" : [ {
    "uid" : "11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587",
    "name" : "BL_2.2.2.2",
    "type" : "host",
    "domain" : {
      "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
      "name" : "SMC User",
      "domain-type" : "domain"
    },
    "ipv4-address" : "2.2.2.2",
    "interfaces" : [ ],
    "nat-settings" : {
      "auto-rule" : true,
      "ipv4-address" : "66.66.66.66",
      "ipv6-address" : "",
      "hide-behind" : "ip-address",
      "install-on" : "All",
      "method" : "hide"
    },
    "groups" : [ {
      "uid" : "eebedbc9-ef19-4c68-91d2-cd6ea3fec11d",
      "name" : "network11111",
      "type" : "group",
      "domain" : {
        "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
        "name" : "SMC User",
        "domain-type" : "domain"
      },
      "members" : [ "11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587" ],
      "groups" : [ ],
      "comments" : "",
      "color" : "black",
      "icon" : "General/group",
      "tags" : [ ],
      "meta-info" : {
        "lock" : "unlocked",
        "validation-state" : "ok",
        "last-modify-time" : {
          "posix" : 1683719146105,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-05-10T17:15+0530"
        },
        "last-modifier" : "admin",
        "creation-time" : {
          "posix" : 1683719146105,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-05-10T17:15+0530"
        },
        "creator" : "admin"
      },
      "read-only" : false,
      "available-actions" : {
        "edit" : "true",
        "delete" : "true",
        "clone" : "true"
      }
    }, {
      "uid" : "f04b042d-0a37-4a10-b470-08ca0e18a129",
      "name" : "workrrorxzdg",
      "type" : "group",
      "domain" : {
        "uid" : "41e821a0-3720-11e3-aa6e-0800200c9fde",
        "name" : "SMC User",
        "domain-type" : "domain"
      },
      "members" : [ "11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587" ],
      "groups" : [ ],
      "comments" : "",
      "color" : "black",
      "icon" : "General/group",
      "tags" : [ ],
      "meta-info" : {
        "lock" : "unlocked",
        "validation-state" : "ok",
        "last-modify-time" : {
          "posix" : 1683719351164,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-05-10T17:19+0530"
        },
        "last-modifier" : "admin",
        "creation-time" : {
          "posix" : 1683719351164,
          "iso-8601" : "2023-05-10T17:19+0530"
        },
        "creator" : "admin"
      },
      "read-only" : false,
      "available-actions" : {
        "edit" : "true",
        "delete" : "true",
        "clone" : "true"
      }
    } ],
    "comments" : "",
    "color" : "black",
    "icon" : "Objects/host",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "meta-info" : {
      "lock" : "unlocked",
      "validation-state" : "ok",
      "last-modify-time" : {
        "posix" : 1683514434876,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-05-08T08:23+0530"
      },
      "last-modifier" : "admin",
      "creation-time" : {
        "posix" : 1683514434876,
        "iso-8601" : "2023-05-08T08:23+0530"
      },
      "creator" : "admin"
    },
    "read-only" : false,
    "available-actions" : {
      "edit" : "true",
      "delete" : "true",
      "clone" : "true"
    }
  } ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,network11111,workrrorxzdg
```

Comment: Please add desired output.

Comment: I have added the expected output. Please check..

Comment: Your "combined command" gives the expected output for me.

Comment: Yes right. It was giving me error because of error in json DB. I have now corrected that. Also, thanks to pmf and 0stone0, I have now more than one way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also store it in a variable:

```bash
.objects[] | .groups[].name as $groupsname | [ .name, .uid, .type,
  ."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv6-address",
  ."nat-settings"."install-on", ."nat-settings".method, $groupsname
] | join(",")  # or @csv
```

```
BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,network11111
BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,workrrorxzdg
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Ng87Fe1MZqz)

---

The edited output is even simpler: Just iterate over the array:

```bash
.objects[] | [ .name, .uid, .type,
  ."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv4-address", ."nat-settings"."ipv6-address",
  ."nat-settings"."install-on", ."nat-settings".method, .groups[].name
] | join(",")  # or @csv
```

```
BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,network11111,workrrorxzdg
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mtrloNm1pZT)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\(.groups[].name)` in the string literal

Syntax example with reduced field to keep it simple

```
.objects[] | "\(.name),\(.uid),\(.groups[].name)"
```

```
"BL_2.2.2.2,network11111"
"BL_2.2.2.2,workrrorxzdg"
```

---

With all fields (from OP):

```
.objects[] | "\(.name),\(.uid),\(.type),\(."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv6-address"),\(."nat-settings"."install-on"),\(."nat-settings".method),\(.groups[].name)"
```

```
"BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,network11111"
"BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,workrrorxzdg"
```

---

OP's comment, output as a single line:
Use `join()` in the string literal:

```
.objects[] | "\(.name),\(.uid),\(.type),\(."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv4-address"),\(."nat-settings"."ipv6-address"),\(."nat-settings"."install-on"),\(."nat-settings".method),\([ .groups[].name ] | join(","))"
```

But removing the string literal and using `join()` or `@csv` on an array holding your field makes this a lot easier:

```
.objects[] | [ .name, .uid, .type, .groups[].name ] | join(",")
```

Comment: I need one more help if possible. Can you please help me to get the output as "BL_2.2.2.2,11c758bf-15d7-47ba-af1a-200ffa171587,host,2.2.2.2,66.66.66.66,,All,hide,network11111,workrrorxzdg". In short in a single output

Comment: Well to bad you alter the expected output after accepting the answer. I've changed my answer with a 'better' way.

Comment: Yes right 0stone0, I was gonna work on combining it but you both guys helped me achieve it in much easier and quicker way. I have now more ways from you guys to try in my next jq task. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yea but I mean just keep the desired output the same. Again I spend time answering but you alter the desired output and the answer is un-accepted. Doesn't matter but feels so useless to answer jq questions if they keep changing and my answer becomes outdated..

Comment: I can understand and I apologize for that. Will keep that in mind next time.